# Optimizing SQLite select statement

Tags: javascript, sqlite

Here is my SQLite select statement as of right now:

```
SELECT shifts.*, bases.*, sites.*, students.students_first_name,  
students.students_last_name, count(shifts.shifts_event_id) as count,  
group_concat(shifts.shifts_student_id) as students_id_array,
group_concat(students.students_first_name) as students_first_names_array,  
group_concat(students.students_last_name) as students_last_names_array FROM shifts, bases,
sites, students 
WHERE shifts.shifts_student_id IN (students.students_userRoles_studentRoleData_id) AND 
shifts.shifts_site_id = sites.sites_id AND shifts.shifts_base_id = bases.bases_id AND
shifts.shifts_start_datetime BETWEEN "'+startOfDay+'" AND "'+endOfDay+'" GROUP BY
shifts.shifts_event_id
```

I'm storing information in 4 different tables. Basically I'm trying to match all shifts with the site and base, then get all the students by first and last name that will be attending this shift(event_id is what determines what shift they share).

Right now the sql call finishes running in about 2000ms, I'm wondering if there is anyway to optimize/clean up this lengthy sqlite statement.

Comment: May be you show this tables?

Comment: ... and any indexes.

Comment: Here is the create function: `'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + tableName + ' (' + columns.join(',') + ', UNIQUE('+tableName+'_id))'` If that helps? The tables are so big that in chrome console you cant make-out column names